# Getting a error in browser after running axios POST request, token not defined

Tags: reactjs, express

Still getting comfortable with React api requests. Not sure why the token is undefined after pressing submit button. Here is my questions.js in my api folder.

```js
import apiUrl from '../apiConfig'
import axios from 'axios'

export const createQuestion = (question, user) => {
  return axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: apiUrl + '/create-question',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Token token =${user.token}`
    },
    data: {
      question: {
        question: question.question,
        description: question.description,
        category: question.category
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried console logging the user object before the return line to make sure the token is in there?

Comment: Thank you for the response. It shows undefined for user. I need the user to be the owner if the question so only they can update or delete it. How do I make this work?

Comment: Can you show your other code that calls that function?